# Iptables TTL and bytes limit

Tags: iptables

a task:

prohibit the reception and transmission of all packets whose size exceeds 512 bytes, and the TTL field is more than 30

Do I understand correctly that for TTL it will look like this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A input -j TTL --ttl-set 30 ?
```

But I still need to specify in this rule that the packet does not exceed 512 bytes, how can I do that?

Comment: What's the use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is *changing* the TTL to a specified value – it doesn't *check* the original TTL, so it achieves the exact opposite of what you want. (All uppercase modules used via `-j SOMEACTION` are actions rather than match rules, and `--ttl-set` pretty much says that it will set the TTL.)

To *match* on the TTL, use the `ttl` module, e.g. `-m ttl --ttl-gt 30` in front of the action. Similarly, to match on packet length, use the `length` module, e.g. `-m length --length 0:512`.

Then you can either have two separate rules to drop packets (one that matches too large packets, another that matches too large TTL) or you can have a single rule to accept packets that match both requirements (with both match modules simply specified in the same rule).

Comment: Also, mentioning just in case: _DNS packets can be longer than 512 bytes._